# Right alt works as some kind of shortcut

Tags: 16.04, keyboard, shortcut-keys, special-characters

I don't even know how to properly name this problem. So I use Polish keyboard layout meaning I use <kbd>ALT GR</kbd> fairly often to get special characters.

It works normally but when I want to, say, search for a string in Gedit, I press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>, try to type the string and as soon as I press right <kbd>ALT</kbd>, it loses focus and hides. If I try to rename a file in Nautilus, the field loses its focus and gets back to the old filename. In LibreOffice when I try to search a string, pressing right <kbd>ALT</kbd> highlights everything I've typed so far, so I'm unable to search a given string.

Does anybody know what it is? I have to say it's horribly annoying because <kbd>ALT GR</kbd> just interrupts work apparently doesn't do anything else. I've checked keyboard shortcuts and run

```
dpkg-reconfigure keyboard
```

and everything looks fine. I've searched forums but it seems like no one else has ever had a problem like that.

Thanks in advance!
Greg

Comment: Try `xmodmap -e 'keycode 203='` and then `xmodmap -e 'keycode 203=Mode_switch'`. This will reset the key 203, AltGr.

Answer (score 0):

I guess your `AltrGr`-key is configured as a compose-key, this enables you to use multiple keystrokes to *compose* your characer.

eg. the `compose`-key, `'` and `e` will output `é`